# JQuery AddClass in Each Function Weirdness

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I have a jquery(1.11.1) function firing on `$('document')ready()` that is iterating over dom elements and doing a match on a localStorage value to set some classes if the itemIDs match. My console logging is showing that the items are matching but the removeClass and addClass functions are not working where matches are found:
```

```
//process and highlight any existing favorites from localStorage
$('.snippet-star-box i').each(function () {
   var itemType = $(this).data('type');
   var itemId = $(this).data('id');
   var allFaves = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("my-faves"));
   if(allFaves){
      $.each(allFaves, function(i, item) {
          if (allFaves[i].id === itemId) {
              console.log("Matched Fave :" + itemId);
              $(this).removeClass('glyphicon-star-empty').addClass('glyphicon-star fave');
          }
      });
   }
});
```

The console output is showing matches:
    `Matched Fave :171
    Matched Fave :170`

Not sure whats happening here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store the icon dom element from your outer each loop in a variable in order to use it in your inner each loop, because `this` is not the icon dom element in the second loop (closure), and i would suggest you move the `allFaves` variable outside of the loop, otherwise you will be getting and parsing it from the storage for each item:

```
var allFaves = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("my-faves"));
$('.snippet-star-box i').each(function () {
   var $this = $(this);
   var itemType = $this.data('type');
   var itemId = $this.data('id');
   if(allFaves){
      $.each(allFaves, function(i, item) {
          if (allFaves[i].id === itemId) {
              console.log("Matched Fave :" + itemId);
              $this.removeClass('glyphicon-star-empty').addClass('glyphicon-star fave');
          }
      });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding `$(item).removeClass('glyphicon-star-empty').addClass('glyphicon-star fave');` instead of `$(this).removeClass('glyphicon-star-empty').addClass('glyphicon-star fave');`

Answer (score 0):

Had to set a var for $(this) for reference in the nested each. The $(this) inside the nested each was referring to the localStorage items:

    `$('.snippet-star-box i').each(function () {
     var $item = $(this);
     var itemType = $(this).data('type');
     var itemId = $(this).data('id');
     var allFaves = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("my-faves"));
     if(allFaves){
        $.each(allFaves, function(i, item) {
            if (allFaves[i].id === itemId) {
                console.log("Matched Fave :" + itemId);
                $item.removeClass('glyphicon-star-empty').addClass('glyphicon-star fave');
            }
        });
     }
    });`